# Split a column into three column

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

I wan to divide fetched a single column from database in three different columns. 
The below code gives me one column image_url.

```
public function fetch() 
    {
        $model = Image::select('image_url');
        return Datatables::eloquent($model)->make(true);
    }
```

I want to split this column into three columns before returning it.
as for now it is returned in this form..

```
{
 "draw": 0,
 "recordsTotal": 16,
 "recordsFiltered": 16,
 "data": [
     {
      "image_url": "public/uploaded_images/2019_08_27_WheatMaizeBanner_1.png"
     },
     {
      "image_url": "public/uploaded_images/2019_08_27_WheatFlourBanner1.jpg"
     },
     {
      "image_url": "public/uploaded_images/2019_08_27_TurDalBanner1.jpg"
     },
     {
      "image_url": "public/uploaded_images/2019_08_27_TurBanner1.png"
     }
   ]
}
```

But I want something like this

```
{
 "draw": 0,
 "recordsTotal": 16,
 "recordsFiltered": 16,
 "data": [
   {
    "image1": "public/uploaded_images/2019_08_27_WheatMaizeBanner_1.png",
    "image2": "public/uploaded_images/2019_08_27_WheatFlourBanner1.jpg"
    "image3": "public/uploaded_images/2019_08_27_TurBanner1.png"
   }
  ]
}
```

Comment: use `pluck()` instead of `select()`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function fetch() 
    {
        $model = Image::select('image_url');
        $result = Datatables::eloquent($model)->make(true);
        $data = [];
        foreach($result->data as $i => $record) {
            $data['image' . ($i+1)] = $record->image_url;
        }
        $result->data = [ (object)$data ];
        return $result
    }
```